# Complex Analysis: Taylor's Theorem Proof (Question about first line)

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Theorem: "If *f* is analytic in the disk |z-z_0| < R, then the Taylor Series converges to f(z) for all z in the disk. Furthermore, the convergence of the series is uniform in any closed subdisk |z-z_0| <= R' < R

Proof: It is enough to prove uniform convergence on all closed subdisks |z-z_0| <= R' (why?)

Can someone help in answering the (why?) part of the proof. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? Because for each $z$ in the disc $|z-z_0|<R$ there exists a positive number $R' < R$ such that $z$ is contained in the closed subdisc $|z-z_0| \le R'$: simply take 
$$R' = \frac{|z-z_0| + R}{2}
$$

Comment: Tremendous thank you